# The best way to handle onBeforeUnload

Tags: javascript, ajax

I know that onBeforeUnload does not work on all browsers. But how to handle (at least for browsers that works) this for different browser plus version.

It seems that IE, Chrome, and Firefox handle it differently.

Comment: It depends on what you want to do on `onBeforeUnload` event.

Comment: i want to call a function that open a page like: `xmlhttp.open("GET", "count_visit.php?t=" + (((new Date()).getTime() - startime) / 1000), false);`. this function also have an alert code like alert('ok')

Comment: why would you want to do that.Sorry but give us all the details. Basically browsers tend not to implement this event at all because it's a "bad move" for developers to use it as long as browser make all the cleaning after the page stops. And opening a page after leaving another this is just sick;

Comment: no. i will not open the page as a popup. as what you can see on my comment above i am using XMLHttpRequest just to log who close the browser or navigate to other page.

Comment: *just to log the visit after it close the browser*